# Regex or-operator works with + quantifier but not with *

Tags: regex

I'm having quite a hard time figuring out what I got wrong about regular expressions. I have a quite complex regex, but for simplifying stuff a little, this is enough for explaining myself:

```
(a*) | (b*)
```

Not sure if the parenthesis are needed? However this regex is matching a* but not b* (as a, aa, ... and b, bb, ...). If I use + instead of stars, it works except it obviously doesn't match an empty string, which it should. I've tested this on regex101 without any flags.

So why can't the or-operator be used with parts that match empty strings, or is it something else I'm getting wrong here?

Comment: You can, but the first alternative matches *everywhere*, before each non-`a` or sequences of `a`, "wins", and the second and the rest are not even tested. What is that you need to do?

Comment: `a*` matches the empty substring at the start of the string. Why would it consider `b*`?

Comment: In some regex flavours, the longest match wins, in others, the first match wins and you'd need to find another alternative. Which flavour are you using, and might a different one also work?

Comment: I should be using no flavour, just standart regex as this is part of a homework. But maybe `^(a*)|(b*)$` describes a bit better what I need.

Comment: Yes, that is better, as that is most probably wrong. You must be looking for `^(a*|b*)$`. What is the *real-life* scenario?

Comment: There is [no such thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) as "standard regex" ;) Probably the closest thing to "standard" is [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions). But regardless, this is all *probably* not something you need to think about here.

Comment: @Klaus Those `^` and `$` should work pretty much everywhere, if placed in the correct location: `^(a*|b*)$` (or equivalently, `^a*$|^b*$`). They aren't in your question, and I'm not sure what part of your question is still open if you edit it to include them.

Comment: The actual assignement is to write a regex that matches strings whitout any consecutive `a`s or `b`s, while it's guaranteed that the strings only contain `a`s and `b`s. So this is what I came up with: `((ab)*a?)|((ba*)b?)`

Comment: @TomLord That's probably closest to a de facto standard. For a formal standard (and also widely supported), consider the two regular expression syntaxes defined by POSIX.

Comment: @Klaus "The actual assignement is to write a regex that matches strings whitout any consecutive `a`s or `b`s, while it's guaranteed that the strings only contain `a`s and `b`s." -- Okay, I definitely do not see any way to interpret your question that way, and you should probably edit it. Thanks for the clarification already though, it makes your question answerable.

Comment: @Klaus *"write a regex that matches strings whitout any consecutive as or bs"* -- Perhaps this should have been the subject of your question. There are a few different interesting solutions to this.

Comment: @hvd I now found other ways to work out this homework, this is not my actual problem anymore, but I was still wondering why my first attempt didn't work.

Comment: @Klaus this is an inappropriate discussion to be having in the comments section... Your initial attempts are interesting but flawed; you'd need to tackle the problem slightly differently in order to solve this with a regular expression. Please open a new question if you would like me/others to expand on the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your regex *does* match any number of `a`s (possibly zero) or any number of `b`s (also possibly zero). The first sub-expression matches empty strings though, and depending on the regex flavour, that can mean there's no reason to consider whether the `b*` might match. In other words, for the string `bbb`, the match that's found is the zero `a`s that you have before those three `b`s.

You can verify that it could potentially match exactly what you wanted to match by putting markers around it. `^` and `$` work for the normal case, but for demonstration purposes, `X((a*)|(b*))X` may be better: you can easily verify online that it matches `XX`, `XaX`, `XaaX`, `XaaaX`, ..., `XbX`, `XbbX`, `XbbbX`, ...

Comment: Yeah, tested it before with markers, which makes the whole thing a lot easier. But what I'm not getting about this, is why my regexp doesn't match bb as it is longer than an empty substring, shouldn't regex-engines be greedy also in this case?

Comment: @Klaus That's what I meant with regex flavours in my comment: some regex flavours prefer the first alternative that gives a match, others prefer the alternative that gives the longest match. The one you're using (the one on regex101) prefers the first alternative that gives a match, so `a*` will be preferred over `b*`, and `a*` will always match.